# Leaflet : ordering GeoJSON elements inside a layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I'm displaying a GeoJSON layer using leaflet, with the pointToLayer function. Everything works ok so far.

But I would like to display my points in a certain order, based on a property of the GeoJSON. This is important because the radiuses of my points varies with this property, and I need to display the smaller circles on top. I hope I make myself clear.

I've tried many things, but here's what I think is my best try :

```
var pointLayer = L.geoJson(centroids, {
                pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                        fillColor: "#76C551",
                        color: "#000",
                        weight: 1,
                        fillOpacity: 1
                    });
                },
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    var radius = calcPropRadius(feature.properties.nb);
                    layer.setRadius(radius);
                    feature.zIndexOffset = 1/feature.properties.nb*1000;
                    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name + " : " + String(feature.zIndexOffset));
                }
            });
```

You can notice that the zIndexOffset of features can be read in the popups, and they look ok. But the displaying order of the circles doesn't reflect the zIndexOffset.
I've tried using the [setZIndexOffset](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setzindexoffset) method, but as I understand it it works only with markers.

Does anyone know how to do this ? Thanks a lot for any insight !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you figured out, the `zIndexOffset` option is only for `L.marker`'s.

`L.circleMarker`'s go into the [`overlayPane`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-overlaypane) and you can re-order them one to each other using [`.bringToFront()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-bringtofront) and [`.bringToBack()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-bringtoback) methods.

Comment: Thanks ! But is it possible to access the property I want to use to order my markers in the overlay pane ? As far as I can see, circle markers don't retain GeoJSON properties, but I may be wrong !

Comment: As long as you use `L.geoJson()` to convert your GeoJSON data into Leaflet layers, it should automatically add the GeoJSON feature data into each `circleMarker.feature` member. Feel free to open a new question if you have troubles on that. As for ordering, you might also be interested in that post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166252/geojson-layer-order-in-leaflet-0-7-5/167904#167904

Comment: I'm sorry but event though your answer gives me some hints I can't make it work. Could you give an example or maybe a jsfiddle ? That would be great !

Comment: There is already a JSFiddle in the linked post from my above comment. If you still need help, please at least provide your JSFiddle.

Comment: You were right, everything is in your jsfiddle. I didn't get at first how geojson elements can be manipulated as layers, but I get it now. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Whereas ghybs answer works perfectly for leaflet 0.7, switching to leaflet 1.0 allows the use of panes which makes for an easier solution :

```
var pointLayer = L.geoJson(centroids, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                    fillColor: "#76C551",
                    color: "#000",
                    weight: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 1
                });
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                var radius = calcPropRadius(feature.properties.nb);
                layer.setRadius(radius);
                layer.setStyle({pane: 'pane'+ feature.properties.nb});
                var currentPane = map.createPane('pane' + feature.properties.nb);
                currentPane.style.zIndex = Math.round(1/feature.properties.nb*10000);
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name + " : " + String(feature.zIndexOffset));
            }
        });
```

Hope it can be of use to someone else !