# Leaflet Circle Z-Index

Tags: javascript, leaflet, z-index, geojson

I'm drawing a route using `Leaflet`.

The route is divided in frames, each frame is marked with a circle and on hover event the frame shows up with as an opaque overlay over the route.

[image]

The issue is that the circle is drawn behind the frame overlay but I want it on top of everything (on the z-axis).

I've searched and tried everything I've found but I can't make it stay on top.. What can I do?

This is what I'm doing:

```
L.geoJson(route, {
  style: function(feat) {
    return {
      weight: 10,
      opacity: 1,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      color: 'transparent',
      className: 'journey-frame'    
    }
  },
  onEachFeature(feat, layer) {
    var c = layer.getBounds().getCenter()
    var color = getColor()
    var circle = L.circle(c, {
      color: 'black', 
      weight: 2, 
      radius: 3,
      fill: true, 
      fillColor: color,
      fillOpacity: 1,
      className: 'frame-circle',
      zIndexOffset: 1000 // first attempt to place circle on top. Not working
    })

    // second attempt. Not working
    circle.bringToFront()

    // Change layer color to show frame
    layer.on('mouseover', function() {
      layer.setStyle({color: '#ddd', opacity: 0.8});
    })

    // Change layer color to hide frame
    layer.on('mouseout', function() {
      layer.setStyle({color: 'transparent'});
    })
  }
}).addTo(mymap)
```

In my CSS file

```
.frame-circle {
    z-index: 1000; /* tried also this but still nothing */
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102018/leaflet-ordering-geojson-elements-inside-a-layer/39103997#39103997

Comment: @ghybs I tried it and it's not working, same result even calling `var circle = L.circleMarker(c, { same_options }` and then `circle.bringToFront()`... am I missing something?

Comment: What if you do your `bringToFront` outside the `onEachFeature`, once your layer group is already on map?

Comment: It actually worked! Can you explain (or pointing out some doc to understand) why is behaving this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bringToFront()` only once the layer you use it on is already on map (i.e. outside the `onEachFeature` function).

In your case, you have to wait for the `L.geoJson().addTo(map)`, then retrieve your layer (circle), and now you can use `bringToFront()`.

The reason is very simple: this method acts on the layer's parent node to append the layer at the end (or as the first child in the case of `bringToBack()`). If the layer is not added to map, it is not inserted in DOM and it does not have any parent container where it can be re-ordered (appended / inserted).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and the help! 
Cheers!